# Android Game Score Development using Sq lite database

Tags: android, mysql

I'm Developing a game in android most of the game part is completed but now I'm stuck with developing scores for that.
In my game I'm having a list of users in list view so that if i select an user from that list view and click on submit the game should be started.

I'm having a table called users in my database and it consists of name,games played,games won are the columns in it.so when ever user selects his name from the list view and click on submit the games played column of the particular user should be incremented by 1.if he won the game the games won column should be increment by 1.

The Second scenario is if user selects his name and click on submit games played should be incremented and if he lose the game games won should not be incremented. 
The users in the list view are displayed from the database only so whenever user is selected and submitted automatically the data in the table should be updated.
How to achieve this please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to spend a minute on reading the "Saving Data in SQL Databases" tutorial and have a look at the "android.database.sqlite" package. They pretty much have everything you need.